# PHP Mostrar todos os dados de uma ROW em OPTION e INPUT

Tags: php

Visto estar a criar um projeto meio completo...

Fiz um FORM onde tem a opção <.OPTION.> e <.input.>

o que eu quero é... fazer um Loope onde nessa option ele leve consigo como POST o ID, NOME, EMAIL tudo de uma so rows exemplo.

```
nome | email| id
 1   |  @1  |  1
 2   |  @2  |  2
 3   |  @3  |  3 

  Se escolher esta <option>1</option>, ele posta tudo da row 1.
```

Como faço isso?... Ando perdido.

tentei assim, mas ele simplesmente mostrou tudo apenas 1 detalhes na row e o resto fora da row.

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    { 
      echo "<option value = '".$row['id']."'>".$row['movie_name']."</option>";
      echo "</select>";
      echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$row['movie_name']."' name='movname'  hidden>";
      echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$row['movie_img']."' name='movimg'  hidden>";
    }
```

Simplesmente pegar em todos os Valores da ROW e levar juntamente com a OPTION escolhida e preparar o POST e add tudo... como faço?

Comment: Poderia mostrar a consulta sql antes do while?

Comment: Por que você finaliza o **</select>** dentro do while sem iniciar ele dentro desse loop?

Comment: A questão não éssa... a questão é que eu quero usar Todos os Detalhes do Nome 1 em apenas 1 OPTION.... E não apenas 1 value por cada...

Comment: Nossa, está complicado de entender. posta o código inteiro por favor.

Comment: Porra, eu quero isto <option value="'$row['id'] . $row['movie_name'] . $row['movie_img']'">'$row['movie_name']'</option>, para que depois possa ADD a outra tabela todos esses dados.

Answer (score 0):

Vendo o comentário do autor da pergunta:

....., eu quero isto

```
<option value="'$row['id'] . $row['movie_name'] . $row['movie_img']'">'$row['movie_name']'</option>
```

para que depois possa ADD a outra tabela todos esses dados.

Temos que os inputs devem ser construídos separados por um "separador". No exemplo abaixo o separador é uma virgula `,` mas pode ser qualquer um que não esteja presente nos dados da consulta.

```
echo "<option value=".$row['id'].",".$row['movie_name'].",".$row['movie_img'].">".$row['movie_name']."</option>";
```

Se $row['id']=`1`, $row['movie_name']= `Os dalmatas` e $row['movie_img']= `img1`

o resultado de `$_POST["nameSelect"]` é `1,Os dalmatas,img1`

Daí para frente é com [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)  e [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)